# Java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, исключения, netbeans

Есть следующая программа, которая читает данные из текстового файла, формирует на их основе строки для подключения к `postgresql` базе данных, затем подключается к базе данных и результаты запроса записываются в текстовый файл:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Readdata {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
            public static void configureForNexentaSearch(String fileName, String url, String user, String password)
            {
                 String hostAddress="";
                 String databaseName="";
                 try
                 {
                    BufferedReader confFileForNexentaSearch = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
                    hostAddress = confFileForNexentaSearch.readLine();
                    databaseName = confFileForNexentaSearch.readLine();
                    user  = confFileForNexentaSearch.readLine();
                    password = confFileForNexentaSearch.readLine();
                    confFileForNexentaSearch.close();
                 }
                 catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                 {
                    System.out.println("File was not found");
                    System.out.println("or could not be opened.");
                 }
                 catch(IOException e)
                 {
                    System.out.println("Error reading.");
                 }
                url="jdbc:postgresql://"+hostAddress+":5432/"+databaseName;
               PrintWriter debugFileForParams = null;
               try
               {
                    debugFileForParams = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:/urluserpassword.txt"));
               }
               catch(FileNotFoundException e)
               {
                    System.exit(0);
               }
               debugFileForParams.println(url);
               debugFileForParams.println(user);
               debugFileForParams.println(password);
               debugFileForParams.close();              
            }   
        public static void readUsingDataFromDatabase(ArrayList<String> therms, ArrayList<Integer> idOfFiles, ArrayList<Integer> countThermsInFiles, String url, String user, String password, int countFiles)
        {
            Connection con = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;        
            String currentFile;
            int countThermsInFile;
            int countRows=0;
            try
            {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                        st = con.createStatement();
                        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT a.value, c.value, c.id FROM therms a INNER JOIN therm_occurs b ON b.therm_id = a.id INNER JOIN fs_entries c ON b.file_id = c.id ORDER BY a.value, c.value, c.id");
                rs.first();
                therms.add(rs.getString(1));
                countThermsInFile=1; 
                currentFile=rs.getString(2); 
                idOfFiles.add(rs.getInt(3)); 
                countFiles=1;
                countRows=1;
                while (rs.next()) 
                { 
                    if (currentFile!=rs.getString(2)) 
                        {
                            countThermsInFiles.add(countThermsInFile); 
                            countFiles+=1; 
                            currentFile=rs.getString(2); 
                            countThermsInFile=1; 
                            idOfFiles.add(rs.getInt(3)); 
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            countThermsInFile+=1; 
                        }; 
                    therms.add(rs.getString(1));
                    countRows+=1;
                };
                countThermsInFiles.add(countThermsInFile); 
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           PrintWriter debugFile = null;
           PrintWriter debugFileForTherms = null;
           PrintWriter debugFileForIds = null;
           PrintWriter debugFileForCounts = null;
           try
           {
                debugFile = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:/resultset.txt"));
           }
           catch(FileNotFoundException e)
           {
                System.exit(0);
           }
           //debugFile.println(countRows);
           debugFile.println(countFiles);
           debugFile.println();

           for (int i=0; i<therms.size(); i++)
           {     
                debugFile.println(therms.get(i));
           }
           debugFile.println();

           for (int i=0; i<idOfFiles.size(); i++)
           {     
                debugFile.println(idOfFiles.get(i));
           }
           debugFile.println();

           for (int i=0; i<countThermsInFiles.size(); i++)
           {     
                debugFile.println(countThermsInFiles.get(i));
           }
           debugFile.println();

           debugFile.close();
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
                    int countFiles=0; 
            String url = "";
            String user = "";
            String password = "";

            configureForNexentaSearch("D:/paramsforconnection.txt", url, user, password);

            ArrayList<String> therms = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Integer> idOfFiles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ArrayList<Integer> countThermsInFiles = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            readUsingDataFromDatabase(therms, idOfFiles, countThermsInFiles, url, user, password, countFiles);  
    }
}
```

В результате выполнения программы `netbeans`  выдает следующую ошибку

```
run:
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at Readdata.readUsingDataFromDatabase(Readdata.java:67)
    at Readdata.main(Readdata.java:155)
ПОСТРОЕНИЕ УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНО (общее время: 0 секунд)
```

И это несмотря на свойства проекта, указанные на рисунке

[image]

Если кто знает - ответьте пожалуйста, очень надо.

P.S. см. http://www.sql.ru/forum/1027020/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for . Причина стала ясна, но возник другой вопрос: Каким же образом процедура (функция, не возвращающая значение) может изменить значения входных параметров? Функцию использовать не могу, т. к. надо изменить значения нескольких входных параметров.

Comment: Скорее всего неверная строка подключения к  драйверу, вот [здесь][1] например не хватало в конце "/"!


  [1]: http://www.sql.ru/forum/545070/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc-postgresql-5432

Comment: @Rams666 это не помогло, да и зря наверно пробовал, судя по http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/ .

Comment: А 67 строчка [at Readdata.readUsingDataFromDatabase(Readdata.java:67)] - это что?

Comment: @Rams666 я добавлял `+ "/"` в указанную вами строку, затем нажимал `F6` (запуск проекта в `Netbeans`) и получал те же сообщения. Если есть сомнения, то я могу привести скриншот с текстом и результатом выполнения.

Comment: @ivan89, я уже понял, что дело не в "/", но есть подозрение, что все же url неверный! Сейчас хочу узнать, что у вас в 67-й строчке программы, чтобы увидеть, в каком месте программы падает exception? И еще, можете показать, какой в итоге url у Вас получается?

Comment: @Rams666 67 строка

    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
вывод в файл

       PrintWriter debugFileForParams = null;
       try
       {
      debugFileForParams = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("D:/urluserpassword.txt"));
       }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
       {
      System.exit(0);
       }
       debugFileForParams.println(url);
       debugFileForParams.println(user);
       debugFileForParams.println(password);
       debugFileForParams.close();
показал, что

url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.8:5432/NexentaSearch

Comment: @Rams666 см. http://www.sql.ru/forum/1027020/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for . Причина стала ясна, но возник другой вопрос: Каким же образом процедура (функция, не возвращающая значение) может изменить значения входных параметров? Функцию использовать не могу, т. к. надо изменить значения нескольких входных параметров.

Comment: попробуйте при запуске приложения вызвать следующий кусок кода:

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

p.s. в зависимости от версии драйвера class name/package может отличатся от приведеных поищите его из eclipse в самой либе подключеной к проэкту

Comment: @ivan89, процедура может изменить значение входных параметров, поскольку вы передаете ей ссылку на переменную, и по этой ссылке переменная остается доступна и внутри процедуры!